# Functions in class don't recognize mysqli object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have problem with my PHP Thread class, although I pointed `$this->mysqli` variable on working `$mysqli` in constructor I am getting `NULL` for that variable in functions inside that class.

```
class Process extends Thread {

    protected $counter;
    protected $mysqli;

    public function __construct($name, Counter $counter, $mysqli )
    {
        var_dump($mysqli); // here connection exist

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->counter = $counter;
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;

    }

    public function run() { 

        var_dump($this->mysqli); // here connection doesn't exist (empty mysqli object)

        $address = new Link($this->mysqli, $this->name);
        $address->insertName($this->name);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Link` class?

Comment: @Fred-ii- that part isn't important, that class have more than 500 lines of code, point is that $this->mysqli dont work inside functions (empty mysqli object)